# C# - Make a project MySQL and SQL Server compatible

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database

I am working on a project that I want both **MySQL** and **MSQL** compatible.
All is working good, but I have a small issue about code repeating :

I have a separate class for all database queries, and for selects, I do the following (example for an object "Profil"):

I have a parameter "isMySQL" that I set to true if I want to use MySQL and false for using Microsoft SQL Server.

```
public Profil Select_profil(string query)
        {
            Profil profil = new Profil();
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                if (this.isMySQL)
                {
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.Replace("[myDataBase].", ""), connection);
                    using (MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            profil.ID = Int32.Parse(dataReader["ID"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.Nom = dataReader["PROFIL"].ToString().Trim();
                            profil.Famille = dataReader["FAMILLE"].ToString().Trim();
                            profil.Largeur = double.Parse(dataReader["LARGEUR"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.Hauteur = double.Parse(dataReader["LARGEUR_AILE"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.EpAile = double.Parse(dataReader["EP_AILE"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.EpAme = double.Parse(dataReader["EP_AME"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.Radius1 = double.Parse(dataReader["R"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.Radius2 = double.Parse(dataReader["R2"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.PdsLin = double.Parse(dataReader["PDS_LINEAIRE"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.PaintSurf = double.Parse(dataReader["PAINT_SURF"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.P08 = double.Parse(dataReader["P08"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.P09 = double.Parse(dataReader["P09"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.P10 = double.Parse(dataReader["P10"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.P11 = double.Parse(dataReader["P11"].ToString().Trim());
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, MSconnection);
                    using (SqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (dataReader.Read())
                        {
                            profil.ID = Int32.Parse(dataReader["ID"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.Nom = dataReader["PROFIL"].ToString().Trim();
                            profil.Famille = dataReader["FAMILLE"].ToString().Trim();
                            profil.Largeur = double.Parse(dataReader["LARGEUR"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.Hauteur = double.Parse(dataReader["LARGEUR_AILE"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.EpAile = double.Parse(dataReader["EP_AILE"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.EpAme = double.Parse(dataReader["EP_AME"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.Radius1 = double.Parse(dataReader["R"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.Radius2 = double.Parse(dataReader["R2"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.PdsLin = double.Parse(dataReader["PDS_LINEAIRE"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.PaintSurf = double.Parse(dataReader["PAINT_SURF"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.P08 = double.Parse(dataReader["P08"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.P09 = double.Parse(dataReader["P09"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.P10 = double.Parse(dataReader["P10"].ToString().Trim());
                            profil.P11 = double.Parse(dataReader["P11"].ToString().Trim());
                        }
                    }
                }
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
            return profil;
        }
```

For MySQL and SQL Server, the code is the same(except the **[MyDatabase].**, that I replace in case of MySQL), but I need to repeat it twice because in one case I use objects MySqlCommand and MySqlDataReader, in the second case I need to use SqlCommand and SqlDataReader.
Inconvenient is when I make some modify in my database, I need to change all twice (source of errors).
Is there a way to group the code and put it once, without using functions?

Comment: I have done this using System.Data.Common.DbCommand (not SqlCommand, not mysqlCommand) – the only thing I changed was the connection string and the core factory that created my connections objects x.OpenConnection().  I hid many other problems behind stored procs and dynamically changing the raw sql syntax in a few rare instances.  The MySql and SqlServer libraries were not even referenced in the main data layer.  The DbCommand abstract interface gets rid of the IF ELSE problem you see,

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, I think I will begin by that System.Data.Common.DbCommand, it seems to be my starting point. Would you have please a link on some examples how to use it, because for now couldn't find much about it.

Comment: @Siegfried.V rather than edit your question to include the answer, you should add your own answer, which you can accept.

Comment: @Richardissimo, ok I will do so, I just believed that I may accept zacs's answer, as he gave me the solution.

Comment: You can of course accept Zacs answer and/or upvote it if you found it helpful. I took the fact that you put an answer in your question that Zacs answer didn't quite do it for you. It's just more helpful for future visitors, if questions have accepted answers, and saves people who might want to help from coming to "a question without an accepted answer", when actually it has been answered.

Comment: @Richardissimo I understand. In fact I hesitated to mark zacs answer as the good one, but as you also commented, it was not so clear as it was in comments. So I will wait he edits his answer to mark it as solution, then delete mine. More fair to him as he is the one that gave me the solution. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying the switching logic in if..else.. statement here, you should write a separate layer for data access, as suggested in previous comments.
That layer would deal with the database selection and other operation.

for example, 
Add a contract say, ICommand -- this would be used at your current code in place of MySQLCommand or SQLCommand.
A data access layer would have a factory/class and function that would return you the appropriate command based on the parameter.

Similarly, all other operation related to database, that you might be doing in your code, at business layer, would be moved to this new layer that you would create, DataAccessLayer.

**Edited:**
Thanks @Richardissimo and @Siegfried.V for accepting it as an answer. As suggested, I put here the code so that you can accept it as an answer.

```
public IDataReader ExecuteReader(string query) 
    {
         IDataReader dataReader = null; 
       if (this.isMySQL) 
      {
         MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.Replace("[myDataBase].", ""), 
         connection); 
         dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
      } 
      else 
      { 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection); 
        dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
      }
        return dataReader; 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks but for now I could not understand much from last posts, I don't know what means write separate layer, don't know what is a contract or ICommand ... Now I am searching information about System.Data.Common.DbCommand as advised by SQL Surfer it seams to be a good beginning, but hard to find some info on how to use it

Comment: You should learn about layered architecture to make the application more reusable and easy maintainable.start by googling about it.

for now, a simple approach could be create a helper class and a method that would do the decision part and query execution part and return the data result.

Comment: Please refer below sample code for reference...
`public IDataReader ExecuteReader(string query, string connection)
        {
            IDataReader dataReader = null;
            if (this.isMySQL)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.Replace("[myDataBase].", ""), connection);
                dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
            return dataReader;
        }`

Comment: now, call this function from your code like...
`IDataReader reader = ExecuteReader(query, connection);`
and then use this reader to get the values

Comment: Thanks for your function, it works great, except for "connection", that is not a string but an object. I will edit my question including your solution as I did it. About layered architecture, after googling, I think that's what I did. In fact functions linked to database are all in a separate .dll file. but until now I had only MySQL, then decided to implement also SQL server(for cost question). What was missing to me was "IDataReader", it solved everything.

Comment: @zacs, you should take the code from those comments and edit them into your answer (and delete the comments).

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use different database engines and select either one in a particular installation from settings, you should have a data access layer that implements an interface for the optional database engines. For this, one option is to have an abstract class and inherit from it to implement peculiarities for each database engine. Have a factory that instantiates the required implementation and use it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zacs for his solution, I put here the code :

```
public List<Profil> Select_profil(string query)
        {
            List<Profil> list = new List<Profil>();
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                IDataReader dataReader = ExecuteReader(query);
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    ...
                    ...
                }
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Then ExecuteReader function :

```
public IDataReader ExecuteReader(string query)
        {
            IDataReader dataReader = null;
            if (this.isMySQL)
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query.Replace("[v-steel].", ""), connection);
                dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, MSconnection); 
                dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }
            return dataReader;
        }
```

Regarding connection ant MSconnection, these are two private objects :

```
private MySqlConnection connection;
private SqlConnection MSconnection;
```